# Regular expressions that exclude a match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to learn how to construct a refular expression that matches all paths under `/fs` except for `/fs/a.txt` and `/fs/b.txt`. This regular expression needs to begin with `^` and end with `$`. I've looked at other expressions for matching patterns that exclude a particular string, but they are not restricted to beginning/end regexes. How do I construct the regex I need?

Comment: a "refular expression"? Add the tag for the language or tool you use.

Comment: Try `/^\/fs\/(?!a\.txt$)(?!b\.txt$).*$/`. Do you actually have any attempt of your own?

Comment: Or `/^\/fs\/(?!(?:a|b)\.txt).*$/`

Comment: or `\/fs\/[^ab]{1}\.txt`  like [here](https://regex101.com/r/cB6sO6/1)

Comment: @neuronet  You can golfcode that even more ;) The `{1}` adds nothing.

Comment: hehe `\/fs\/[^ab]\.txt` :P

Comment: @neuronet I think `a.txt` and `b.txt` are only examples and the actual file names are way more complicated than that.

Comment: @Xufox or Melab likes short filenames very much :)

Comment: @neuronet It's an example that conforms to my requirements.

Comment: @Xufox See my reply to neuronet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the discard technique by using verbs like SKIP and FAIL (only supported in PCRE).

You can have a regex like this:

```
/fs/[ab]\.txt(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|/fs/.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD6uW2/1)**

If you don't have PCRE engine, then you can put the patterns you want to discard at the beginning and set capturing groups for the pattern you want, like this:

```
/fs/[ab]\.txt|(/fs/.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kD6uW2/2)**

A sample diagram showing the idea would be

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Of course, you will have to grab the content from the capturin group with the group index `1`